# What font type is it on the Tab bar (at the bottom)?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I just want to know what that is so that I can match with the font I'm gonna use on the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helvetica.